# Smooth homotopic maps and closed forms..

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms

Does anyone have any idea for showing the following: Let $f_0, f_1:M\rightarrow N$ smooth homotopic maps between the manifolds $M$ and $N$. Suppose $M$ is compact with no boundary. Show that for every closed form $\omega\in \Omega^m(N)$ (where $m=\dim M$), $$\int_{M}f_0^*\omega=\int_Mf_1^*\omega.$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $F:M\times I\rightarrow N$ be a smooth homotopy between $f_0$ and $f_1$.

Then, since $d$ commutes with pullbacks and by Stokes's theorem, we have

\begin{align*} 0 &= \int_{M\times I} F^\ast d\omega \\ &= \int_{M\times I} dF^\ast \omega\\ &= \int_{\partial(M\times I)} F^\ast \omega \\ &= \int_{M\times\{1\}} F^\ast \omega - \int_{M\times\{0\}}F^\ast \omega\\ &= \int_M f_1^\ast\omega - \int_Mf_0^\ast \omega. \end{align*}

Comment: I promise that this will be my last inane/pestering comment on the topic of pullbacks via homotopic maps giving the same integral, but do you have some sort of reference for the above answer? I've looked through Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* and *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*, Spivak's *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry*, Tu's *An Introduction to Manifolds* and tons of stuff online to no avail. I'm keen to see the derivation in context and with a bit of background. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter4075:  It's certainly not inane or pestering!  Please feel free to keep the questions coming!   (I just thought that, perhaps, John Hughes didn't like our conversation pinging him).  To actually answer your question - I just looked through my books and tried to google it, and I failed to come up with a reference!  I'm happy to try to answer any additional questions you have about it, though.

Comment: Thanks for looking. It's such a neat proof that I'm surprised I can't find more references. There's a similar, Stoke's related answer by Alonso Delfín here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325208/integrals-of-pullbacks And Shifrin does the same thing in *Multivariable Mathematics* using a cylinder $S^{1}\times\left[0,1\right]$ for your $M\times I$, and that's all I've able to find.