# Integrals of Pullbacks

Tags: integration, differential-topology, closed-form, differential-forms, compact-manifolds

This is a problem from Guillemin's Differential Topology:

> *Suppose that $f_0, f_1: X \to Y$ are homotopic maps and that the compact boundaryless manifold $X$ has dimension $k$. Prove that for
>   all closed $k$-forms $\omega$ on $Y$, $$ \int_X f_0^*\omega = \int_X
> f_1^*\omega.$$*

There is a hint to use a result from a previous exercise, which says that if $f:\partial W \to Y$ is a smooth map that extends to all of $W$ and $\omega$ is a closed $k$-form on $Y$, with $k = \dim \partial W$, then

$$\int_{\partial W} f^*\omega = 0.$$

It seems to me this should be a straightforward exercise, but I can't get it done. Any hints?

Comment: A homotopy gives you a map $f:X\times I\rightarrow Y$ where the boundary is $X\sqcup X$.

Comment: Isn't the symbol $\sqcup$ used to denote disjoint unions?

Comment: Yes, which is what Joe Johnson is denoting. More precisely the boundary is $X \sqcup -X$, where the latter means $X$ with the opposite orientation.

Comment: As Joe Johnson said, the homotopy is a map,f:X×I→Y. $f^*(\omega)$ is a closed form on X×I. By Stokes theorem its integral over the boundary is zero. But the integral over the boundary is the difference of the integrals of $f^*_0(\omega)$ and $f^*_1(\omega)$ over X.

Comment: @DouglasFinamore are you still looking for an answer? It seems like these comments cover it. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, the comments have made it clear. I've read a little more about boundaries and stuff and understood it after some time. Thank you all.

Answer (score 7):

> Following the hint, if $F: \partial W \to Y$ is a smooth map that extends to all $W$ and $\omega$ is a closed $k$-form on $Y$, then $d\omega=0$, thus Stokes Theorem gives 
>   $$
> \int_{\partial W} F^*\omega = \int_{W} d(F^*\omega) =\int_{W} F^*(d\omega) = \int_W 0 = 0 \tag{1}
> $$

Now let $F: X \times I \to Y$ be an homotopy between $f_0$ and $f$. Since $X\times I$ is a boundary manifold, with boundary given by $X\times \{ 0 \} \cup X \times \{ 1 \}$, where $\{ 0\}$ has orientation $-1$ and the orientation of $\{ 1 \}$ is $+1$, then
$$
\int_{\partial(X \times I)} F^* \omega = \int_{ X \times \{ 1 \}} F^*\omega -  \int_{ X \times \{ 0 \}} F^*\omega = \int_{X} f_1^* \omega -\int_{X} f_0^* \omega 
$$
However by (1), it follows that $\int_{\partial(X \times I)} F^* \omega=0$, hence the claim follows.

Answer (score 2):

We need to use the *Natural Transformation Law* defined in Guillemin p.168 and p.176:

> If $f:Y\to X$ is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism, then $\int_X{\omega}=\int_Y{f^*\omega}$ for every compactly supported, smooth $k$-form on $X$.

We can now claim  $\int_X{f^*_j\omega}=\int_Y{\omega}$, where $j=0$ or $1$, which would be enough, but we observe that $\omega$ is closed in $Y$, and it's pullback might be bounded in $X$.

So $\int_X{f^*_j\omega}$ is misleading, and we should write $\int_{X \cup \partial X}{f^*_j\omega}$. But this means we have $\int_{X \cup \partial X}{f^*_j\omega}=\int_X{f^*_j\omega}+\int_{\partial X}{f^*_j\omega}$, and the second integral on the RHS is zero, so the result holds.

Comment: @LeoSera: The answerer has written $X + dX$ instead of $X \cup \partial X$. I shall correct this, but I think the idea is clear. Next, as the answerer clearly writes, $k$ in $f_k$ stands for $0$ or $1$, read the answer again carefully. You might want to reconsider the downvote.

Comment: @AlexM. Oh I see, but anyway bad choice putting $k=0,1$ since $k$ is the dimension of the manifold. Still pretty confusing. Also the question had already a clear answer so I am keeping the downvote !