# Homotopic function question - very basic

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms

I've only just “discovered” homotopic functions, so apologies if I'm asking nonsense. Shifrin in *Multivariable Mathematics* (p405) gives an example of a homotopic function as$$H\left(\mathbf{x},t\right)=\left(1-t\right)\mathbf{x},$$

where $f:D^{n}\rightarrow D^{n}$, $f\left(\mathbf{x}\right)=\mathbf{x}$ (here $D^{n}$ is the unit closed ball) and $g\left(\mathbf{x}\right)=0$. For my own curiousity, I'm trying to see how, for the simple example of $D^{2}$, $$\intop_{D^{2}}f^{*}\omega=\intop_{D^{2}}g^{*}\omega,$$which I imagine is blindingly obvious, but I just can't see how to proceed. I'm not even sure what $\omega$ to use (I believe $\omega$ needs to be a closed 2-form on $D^{2}$). Using $\omega=dx\wedge dy$, for the lhs I get$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}dx\,dy=\pi,$$which can't be right as $$\intop_{D^{2}}g^{*}\omega$$ must be zero. Any hints?

EDIT 1. Sorry, I got my original “unit disk” integral wrong. Shifrin says that the pullback integral applies when $X$ is a compact, oriented k-dimensional manifold and $f,g:X\rightarrow$ Y are homotopic maps, and $\omega$ is any closed k-form on $Y$.

EDIT 2. Following from the comment by @Kajelad that this only works if $X$ is boundaryless, I thought I'd try another simple example, ie $f:S^{1}\rightarrow S^{1}$, $f\left(\theta\right)=\theta$ and $g\left(\theta\right)=0$ and try to show $$\intop_{S^{1}}f^{*}\omega=\intop_{S^{1}}g^{*}\omega.$$But, again, I'm not sure how to do this.

EDIT 3. My question has now evolved to simply whether Shifrin's Propostion 7.4 only applies where $X$ is boundryless. Here's Proposition 7.4:

> $X$ is a compact, oriented k-dimensional manifold and
> $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ are homotopic maps. Then for any closed k-form
> $\omega$ on $Y$, we
> have$$\intop_{X}f^{*}\omega=\intop_{X}g^{*}\omega.$$

I can't see where he has defined $X$ as boundryless, but I may have missed that.

An online reference that confirms that $X$ and $Y$ are boundaryless would be most helpful.

Comment: Why do you expect that $\int f^*\omega=\int g^*\omega$ here? This certainly does not hold in general. Also, it seems your double integral should evaluate to $\pi$.

Comment: Your lhs integral doesn't make much sense

Comment: @Kajelad - I've edited my question to show the correct disk double integral, and also to give Shifrin's definition of when the pullback integral applies. Why are you saying it doesn't apply here?

Comment: I would suggest looking closely at the assumptions/proof of the theorem; I suspect it specifies manifolds *without boundary* at some point. The proof by Stokes theorem doesn't work when $M$ has boundary, since in that case $M\times[0,1]$ has corners.

Comment: @Kajelad - He originally defines $X\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $Y\subset\mathbb{R}^{m}$.

Comment: With regards to edit 2, the map $f(\theta)  = \theta$ and $g(\theta) = 0$ are not homotopic as maps to $S^1$.  (And what, exactly, does $g(\theta) = 0$ for a map $g:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ mean?  What do you mean by $0\in S^1$?)

Comment: @JasonDeVito - Yes, after much labour, I eventually discovered that $S^{1}$ is not contractible (new word to me), ie there is no homotopy from the identity map of $S^{1}$ to the constant map. Any chance of answering my Edit 3? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't own Shifrin's book.  But a)  he frequents this website, so he may see this question and b)  If my experience "manifold" is defined as "locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$" (plus some more technical conditions, e.g., Hausdorff, Paracompact).  Can you find where he defines manifolds in the book?  My guess is that he does not allow manifolds to have boundary.  (There is an english/grammar issue here.  A "manifold with boundary" is *not* a manifold with extra structure (a boundary).  Rather, a manifold is a special manifold with boundary: one whose boundary is empty.)

Comment: And your example with the disk shows that the theorem is false without extra hypothesis (e.g. that "manifold" means "manifold without boundary", as is common.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito - Actually, he writes "manifolds without boundary" on the blackboard (about 25 minutes from the start) when he's talking about this in the "Math 3510 Day 44" YouTube video. I'm just intrigued why he hasn't included that condition is his Proposition 7.4.

Comment: Again, I don't have the book - but he must define "manifold" somewhere prior to the theorem.  Does his definition preclude manifolds with boundary?  (Under the definitions of "manifold" I've seen, a manifold with boundary is not a manifold.)

Comment: NO, he explicitly says *with boundary* if boundary is allowed. He never has subscribed to the terminology that forces one to say “without boundary” ad nauseam.

Comment: @TedShifrin - OK, so “manifold” without any qualification means a manifold without boundary? Thus, both $X$ and $Y$ in Proposition 7.4 are referring to manifolds without boundary? Yes? I've been self-studying differential forms for a while now without realising the things had topological applications. Then I came across the Topology section in chapter 8 and was blown away by your explanations of the Brouwer Fixed Point and Hairy Ball theorems. Magic.

Comment: [Related?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1325208/272127)

Comment: @C.F.G:  I don't understand your question.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: if Bounded space $X$ is homotopic to a point then closer of $X$ has bounadry?

Comment: @C.F.G:  I'm sorry, I'm still confused.  $X$ is a subset of what?  $\mathbb{R}^n$?  A general metric space?  And are you assuming anything nice about $X$ topologically?  And when you talk about boundary, are you thinking of boundary in the topological sense?  Or in the manifold-with-boundary sense?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Sorry. I meant $X$ a smooth manifold.

Comment: On a related not, @C.F.G, in general spaces are not "homotopic" -- **functions** are. Two spaces may be homotopy-equivalent, but that's a more complicated definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.

1. The theorem that pullbacks via homotopic maps give the same integral: that's for manifolds, not manifolds-with-boundary. (Where "manifolds" really means "manifolds without boundary". See below.)
2. Your second example, with $S^1$, uses the function $f(\theta) = \theta$, g(\theta) = 0$, and presumably the homotopy

$$
H(\theta, s) = (1-s) \theta
$$

Unfortunately, this doesn't actually work. I'm assuming that Ted defines $S^1$ as the manifold consisting of all the points $\{ (\cos t, \sin t) \mid 0 \le t < 2\pi \}$, with the topology arising from inclusion in $\Bbb R^2$. So what is $f$? $f$ is actually a map $[0, 2\pi] \to [0, 2\pi]$, not a map from $S^1$ to $S^1$. What's hidden here is a map $p$ that identifies a point
$$
\theta \in [0, 2\pi)
$$
with the point
$$
(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) \in S^1.
$$
Because $p$ is a bijection, we can "refer to points in $S^1$ by their polar coordinates," which is how $f$ got defined. But while the function $p$ is continuous, the inverse function $p^{-1}: S^1 \to [0, 2\pi)$ is *discontinuous*, which can be a problem. For the real function you want, from $S^1$ to $S^1$, is defined by taking a point of $S^1$, finding its polar coordinate (i.e., applying $p^{-1}$, applying $f$, and then applying $p$ to get back to the unit circle. In short, you're looking at
$$
F = p \circ f \circ p^{-1},
$$
while talking about $f$. Similarly for $g$.

Now $H$, as written above, *is* a homotopy from $f$ to $g$, so you might hope that
$$
K(u, s) = p( H(p^{-1}(u), s )
$$
would be a homotopy on $S^1$. (Here $u$ denotes an arbitrary point of $S^1$; we extract its polar coordinate, apply $H$, and then push back to the unit circle with $p$.)

If $K$ we defined by composing $H$ with some continuous functions, it really *would* be a homotopy between functions $S^1 \to S^1$. But $p^{-1}$ is discontinuous, so the function $K$ that you're implicitly using...you can't use a continuity argument to show it's a homotopy, and in fact, it's *not*  actually a homotopy. So the thing you'd like to conclude, that
$$
\int_0^2\pi F^{*}\omega = \int_0^{2\pi} G^{*} \omega \tag{1}
$$
cannot be "proved" using the cited theorem, because the hypotheses of the theorem are not all satisfied. And that's a good thing, because, as you observed with your own computations, the two sides of the "equality" in Equation 1 are not, in fact, equal.

In short: there's no contradiction to the claim's in Shifrin's book.

Extra note: The whole manifold-without-boundary thing can confuse people, and rightly so. If I say I have a blue truck, people tend to assume I have a truck, and that it's a little special: it's blue. If I have a friend-with-benefits, you assume that I have a friend. But if I say I have a manifold-with-boundary, you're not allowed to assume I have a manifold? What's up with that?

Well...historically, people started talking about manifolds first -- things like a sphere or a torus, etc. And then they realized that they wanted to slightly generalize this, and *sometimes* allow things like a disk, or a cylinder $S^1 \times [0, 1]$ into the same discussions. These things were not literally manifolds, but they had a LOT of the same properties, so someone thought up the clever name "manifold-with-boundary". But **lots** of things were already known about manifolds that were not true for these new things. (For instance: manifolds have no boundary!) So everyone agreed that m-with-b was a new category, one that included (but was **not included in**) the old category of "just plain old manifolds," because otherwise they'd have to go rewrite everything from the past replacing "manifold" with "manifold-without-boundary". Ugh!

The choice to include the sphere, say, in the collection of manifolds-with-boundary, even though its boundary is empty, might seem peculiar. But it didn't take long for folks to see that if they DIDN'T do this, then lots of theorems would start out "Let M be a manifold or manifold-with-boundary", i.e., lots and lots of the things proved for manifolds-with-nonempty-boundary turned out to also be true for manifolds with empty boundary (i.e., ordinary manifolds). So they made the new term **in**clusive rather than **ex**clusive.

Of course, this little bit of history is mostly fiction --- there wasn't a congress of mathematicians who all agreed that henceforth they'd do things THIS way. It took a while to settle out.  And in the intervening years, I'm sure there have been folks who decided that the old way was stupid, and they were going to change the world and insist on manifold-without-boundary and manifold-with-boundary, and let the word "manifold" die a well-earned death. I don't believe that's caught on, but I could be wrong.

Comment: In terms of the whole "manifold-with-boundary is not a manifold" discussion.  As you say, in english, an "adjective noun" is a special kind of "noun" while in this case, it's not true.  On the other hand, this grammatical construction does seem to be fairly common in mathematics.  Compare "left inverse" with "inverse", "left ideal" with "ideal", "skew field" with "field", "rational sphere" with "sphere", etc.

Comment: Ooh...nice point, Jason. I think that it might be nice for textbook authors, at least at the "introducing manifolds" or "introducing abstract algebra" level, to mention this habit among mathematicians. I don't recall seeing this in Linear Algebra, although I suppose that "left-inverse" might show up in some texts. The more we can explain/clarify our terminology, the better. I don't mean to say students shouldn't be confused at time, but they should be confused about the **right** things, not "how come an X-with-Y isn't also an X?" kinds of things. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes - Thanks. I'm going to have to take some time to digest that. Up until now I just assumed some manifolds had boundaries and some didn't - end of story. I've just discovered that Lee goes into some detail on this in the first chapter of his "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds". Don't suppose you have a reference for the "pullbacks via homotopic maps give the same integral" theorem? I've looked through Lee, Spivak, Munkres and others but can't find it anywhere (which doesn't mean it's not there, just that I couldn't find it).

Comment: It's exactly the theorem that you're talking about  --- the one that says $$\intop_{M}f^{*}\omega=\intop_{M}g^{*}\omega.$$ whenever $f,g$ are homotopic maps from a manifold $M^n$ to a manifold $K$, and $\omega$ is a closed $n$-form on $K$ (should have mentioned closed-ness in my too-glib shorthand). It's pretty much the starting point for deRham cohomology theory.

Comment: @JohnHughes:  I agree.  I wasn't even consciously aware of this grammatical flip until I was teaching an "Intro to proofs" class.  In the context of function composition, one has a notion of left and right inverses.  I was confused by several students' wrong proofs until it finally clicked - "Oh, you're assuming a left inverse is an inverse!"

Comment: @Peter4075:  It's an immediate consequence of Stoke's theorem (if you know that):  Suppose $f,g:M^n\rightarrow K$ are smoothly homotopic maps from a closed orientable (boundaryless) manifold $M$ to a manifold $K$.  Suppose $F:M\times I\rightarrow K$ is such a homotopy with $F(\cdot, 1) = f$ and $F(\cdot, 0) = g$.  Assume further that $\omega$ be a closed $n$-form on $K$.  Since $M$ has no boundary, $\partial(M\times I) = M\coprod - M$, where $-M$ refers to $M$ with opposite orientation.  Further, $d(F^\ast \omega) = F^\ast d\omega = 0$.  So, Stokes's theorem gives ...

Comment: $0 = \int_{M\times I} d(F^\ast \omega) = \int_M F(\cdot, 1)^\ast \omega - \int_M F(\cdot, 0)^\ast = \int_M f^\ast\omega - \int_M g^\ast \omega.$

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I'd have gotten to writing that in another week or two . :(

Comment: @JasonDeVito - Thanks. There's a similar derivation in Shifrin's book with the cylinder, $M\times I=S^{1}\times\left[0,1\right]$, which on a good day I can sort of follow. Is it *necessary* for $K$ to be boundaryless as well as $M$?

Comment: @Peter4075:  Whether or not $K$ has boundary is irrelevant.  $M$ needs to be boundaryless so that we can compute the boundary of $M\times I$.  Also, each time we chat here, John Hughes gets a ping (sorry about that, John !), so perhaps further questions should be relegated to a new post.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary (Based on comments):** The equality
$$\int f^*\omega=\int g^*\omega$$
does not hold in general (e.g. manifolds with boundary). Actually as I searched, *manifold with boundary* has been defined on [page 380](https://books.google.com/books?id=OVYZAQAAIAAJ&dq=Shifrin%20in%20Multivariable%20Mathematics%3A%20manifold%20with%20boundary&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=manifold%20with%20boundary) and after that he considered  **manifold** and **manifold with boundary** distinctive but I couldn't find any remark in the book about avoiding any possibility of ambiguity of these terms. As Shifrin said, the author use redundant term "with boundary" to refer to a manifold with boundary. i.e. he explicitly says *with boundary* if boundary is allowed.

[Here is also a related post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1325208/272127)